# Pageviews and views differences between GA4 and Universal

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Working on "converting" a Google Data Studio report from Universal to GA4 and I am noticing a significant differences with some metrics, such as new users and pageviews

In Universal, I got this for Pageviews
[image]
But I am getting these results on GA4 for the exact same period:
[image]

The same for new users:
[image]
Vs GA4
[image]

I know GA4 and Universal are tracking metrics differently , but it looks to me that the numbers are way different

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking where you were initially and had the same reaction, until I realized that in GA4, the pageview stat is considered an Event and when I went to that section, I found the far more accurate stat (still slightly off from UA but within that percentage margin that Google states may exist). Navigate to Reports > Engagement > Events. The page_view Event should have the more accurate total you are looking for when comparing to the Page View number traditionally found in UA.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any filter to remove query parameters in Universal Analytics?
GA4 does not have filters to remove query parameters. Is your home page, landing page for your campaigns?
In GA4, the dimension you have selected is page path + Query String. In this case URL [page path] will also have details of query parameters.
There might be multiple rows present with home page URL with query parameters appended.